# @testSetup doesn't fire "after-insert-triggers"

Tags: unit-test, data

Title says it all.

"After-insert-triggers" working normally in day-to-day use.
It simply updates one field - no complicated work :)

But the same triggers aren't firing during @testSetup inserts.

1. Is this a Salesforce bug?
2. What workaround can I do?
3. When will Salesforce fix it?
4. Will raising a case help fix it?

Further reference: [how to test after insert trigger when @testSetup annotion is used?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FXsIAM)

Comment: This is most likely user error. It would help if you posted a unit test class with an `@testSetup` method that performs an insert, and the corresponding trigger/apex classes that are supposed to be called.

Comment: I just set this up on a dev org and cannot replicate.

Comment: @ShumonSaha Surely you can share a pseudo-code version that informs us of the structure... The logic itself is unimportant but the structure is necessary to have any hope of helping here.

Comment: is the trigger controlled by any custom setting variable?
probably u not inserting that cs is making u feel trigger doesnt run?

Comment: I set up a test in one of my sandboxes, and my `After Insert` trigger was called just fine from a DML Insert performed in an `@testSetup` method.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - ah yes that was the problem! You can post as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: For all of you future-people reading this, this is why it's important to include details. Without relevant code (pseudocode at the very least), we're stuck with trying to pick out what the problem could be at random. It was quite lucky that @PranayJaiswal was able to pinpoint the issue without seeing any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your trigger entry point is controlled by the custom setting, you will need to make sure you insert the proper configuration data to solve the issue.